# Has anyone successfully used MembershipExtras 6.0 from Compucorp on with CiviCRM 5.66 or newer on WordPress?

Tags: civimember

I have noticed that Membership Extras has not been updating as I've updated the rest of my WordPress CiviCRM extensions and so I am running MembershipExtras 2.1 instead of 6.0.  But now I'm woefully behind on my upgrades and need to know if the latest Civi for WordPress will support MembershipExtras 6.0.   I need to upgrade soon, as the module may be blamed for frequent crashes of my WordPress installation (it seems I frequently have to be on recovery mode).  Has anyone successfully used MembershipExtras 6.0 from Compucorp on with CiviCRM 5.66 or newer on WordPress?

In my latest conversation with CompuCorp I'm told that they have a specially patched version of Civi 5.51.3 that will support it, but I am reluctant to downgrade Civi, and am worried about the unpredictability of the results of that.   Is there a significant risk to downgrading to an older Civi?

Comment: Downgrading is absolutely not safe - I have in extreme situations made some coding changes to downgrade one version.  Downgrading 9 versions is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the complex nature of Membership Extras it is designed and tested to work with a specific and patched version of CiviCRM that Compuco host via our Github. Using Membership Extras with an earlier or newer version of CiviCRM may lead to unexpected issues.

In the extension info.xml file, see the “comments” field where we specify the currently supported version of CiviCRM and have a download link to the correct version: See here:

[https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.membershipextras/blob/a0f3…](https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.membershipextras/blob/a0f3%E2%80%A6)

Currently (at the time of writing) this is a patched version of CiviCRM 5.51.3, which can be found here: https://github.com/compucorp/civicrm-core/releases

This patched version maybe earlier than the latest version of CiviCRM but includes all security patches.

I've tried to update all the places that we list the extension to mention this but if you spot anywhere else then do let me know and I'll update!

Another option to get membership extras is to look into CiviPlus (https://www.civi.plus/). CiviPlus is our hosted version of Civi and brings together all the very best features of the amazing CiviCRM platform from all around the community and combines it with our Compuco know-how to give you the best possible CiviCRM experience. Migrating to CiviPlus is easy using our automated CiviCRM migration tool.